# Applying a CSS style using JavaScript if text field is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have this function in JavaScript which I called using an onclick event in my HTML code:

```
function checkTextField(field) {
if (field.value == '') {
    sheet.insertRule("input:focus {background: #fc9fff;}", 1);
  }
}
```

I've checked that the if statement works by using an alert statement within it instead of the insertrule, but it seems that the css is applied even though the value of the field is not empty. Is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but I've created test HTML file and that test works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style></style>
    <script>
var styleAlreadyAppended = false;
function checkTextField(field) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    if (field.value == '' && styleAlreadyAppended !== true) {
        sheet.insertRule("input:focus {background: #f30;}", 0);
        styleAlreadyAppended = true;
    }
    else if (field.value != '' && styleAlreadyAppended === true) {
        sheet.deleteRule(0);
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="testinput" type="text" value="">
        <button onclick="checkTextField(document.getElementById('testinput'))">test</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on FF36.

Comment: But I think that approach described by Arun P. Johny is better and cleaner.

Comment: Yea but I was supposed to use CSS, but this helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when the check method is executed with an empty element, you are inserting a general rule for `input:focus` which is not removed when focus from the current element is removed.

A better option would be to use a class like

```
function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        field.classList.add('empty')
    } else {
        field.classList.remove('empty')
    }
}
```

then in your stylesheet

```
input.empty:focus {
    background: #fc9fff;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but that didn't change the background of my text box on focus when the text box was empty

Comment: @KristinVernon how is the method used

Comment: `<input type="text" name="title" size="80" class="required" onclick="checkTextField(this);"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can go pure CSS using the `:required` and `:invalid` selector and setting the required attribute on the field.

```
<style>
   input:required:invalid { background: #fc9fff; }      
</style>

<input name="email" required />
```

Live version here: http://jsfiddle.net/devotis/z319pp1f/

I admit it's a bit hostile to start all required fields red.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a better approach is to attach your function to `onchange` event like this

```
<input type="text" onchange="checkTextField" />
```

Comment: but that will only insert the style when the state of the field is changed rather than just having focus

Comment: sorry I meant that you can keep the style with onclick, but check with onchange if value != null and then remove it